# Matplotlib: variable size of subplots?

Tags: python, dynamic, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have a project where I draw and save figures with matplotlib. Since the project itself worked perfectly I recently started refactoring but there is one problem which I have not found a good solution for yet. To split implementation and logging I wrote a logging class which passes the data to a plotting class and there I got an issue: **before runtime I do not know how many subplots will exist in one logging plot/figure**.

So, before refactoring I had a lot of different plotting functions and many if statements. Now I want to pass all that stuff to my plotting class...but I do not have a good idea at the moment how the plotting class should handle this data.

Beforehand I had something like this (here: for 4 subplots):

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axarr[0, 0].set_title("original image")
axarr[0, 0].imshow(oimg, interpolation="none", cmap="gray")

axarr[0, 1].set_title("cost data") 
axarr[0, 1].plot(cost_data, ...)
(...)
```

**Of course I could create like 6 different methods like this in my plotting class for 1, 2, 3, ... subplots but then I have the repetition there again.**

Can I somehow create a **buffer** and **dynamically add a subplot in a loop** or something like that?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Write plotting functions that take an `Axes` object + data as input.  It is the relatively easy to write for-loops over sub-plots + your list of data.

Comment: Yes but I would like the plotting method to create an axes object dynamically so that the plotting class takes any size of input and creates the exact amount of subplots for the input. If I have to feed in the axes object I would have to do `plt.subplots(2, 2)` manually with fixed size everywhere where I want to have data plotted?!

Comment: Separate the logic, one set of functions that plot data on to a single `Axes` and a single dispatcher function that takes in your data + options + config + whatever, creates the figure + axes and then dispatches out to the previously mentioned functions.  That way you get maximum code re-use (and readability!).

Comment: And you can dynamically resize `Axes` objects, but no great built-in tools.

Comment: Would you supply an example? Maybe it is too late for me and I should go to bed but I can not think of a proper solution for the dispatcher function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def plotA(ax, data):
    pass

def plotB(ax, data):
    pass

def dispatcher(data, list_of_plot_types):
    function_map = {'A': plotA, 'B': plotB}
    fig, list_of_axes = plt.subplots(1, len(list_of_plot_types))

    for ax, plot_type in zip(list_of_axes, list_of_plot_types):
        function_map[plot_type](ax, data)
```